# continuous function with zero right-derivative implies it is constant

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f_{r}'(x)=0$ (right-derivative) for all $x\in[a,b)$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$.

My approach is to use MVT:

There exists $c\in(y,x)$ s.t. $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f'(c)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Then,

$0=f_{r}'(x)=\lim_{y\to x^+}f'(c)=\lim_{c\to x^+}f'(c)$,

implying that $f$ is constant. But I think there is some problem on my step using right derivatives. Can anyone help me find the flaws in my proof? Thanks.

Comment: Your proof does not work because the MVT does not hold if $f$ is only right-differentiable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I read your answer. But how can you link this problem to Rolle's theorem? Can you briefly explain your intuition?

Comment: Rolle's theorem uses that the derivative of a differentiable function is zero where it attains its maximum or minimum inside an interval. I used  that the right derivative must be $\le 0$ (or $\ge 0$) at the point where a right-differentiable function attains its minimum (resp maximum).